# how to order column lineary in css

Tags: css

i have this code

```
.admin_div ul {
list-style: none;
width: 525px;
margin: auto;
-webkit-column-count: 2;    
-moz-column-count: 2;    
column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap: 0px;
-moz-column-gap: 0;    
column-gap: 0;}
```

and this

```
.admin_div li {
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px 0;
position: relative;}
```

i have an **ul** and few **li** children.
i want all the li's to be in linear insted of harizontal order.

someone know how to do it??

Comment: what do you mean by linear? vertical? instead of going side by side, you want to go top to bottom?

Comment: If you mean vertically, you can just use `.admin_div li{ display: block; }`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `display: inline-block;` from `.admin_div li { }`